# Deleting unused textures in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

while browsing [here](https://code.google.com/p/opengl-tutorial-org/source/browse/tutorial05_textured_cube/tutorial05.cpp) I noticed something strange.

After loading a compressed texture and getting the ID to the shaders uniform

```
    GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvtemplate.DDS");

    // Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
    GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");
```

He deleted the texture using the ID he got from glGetUniformLocation

```
    glDeleteTextures(1, &TextureID);
```

Shouldn't he use this instead?

```
    glDeleteTextures(1, &Texture );
```

Comment: That should also teach them to use reasonable variable names. ;) Using `TextureID` for the name of a variable that holds a location is just asking for mistakes. Particularly if they use variable names of the form `*ID` for object ids (or, in the official terminology, "names") in the rest of the code.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Funny thing is, that in loadDDS() he returns TextureID.

Comment: @RetoKoradi https://code.google.com/p/opengl-tutorial-org/source/browse/common/texture.cpp

Comment: Considering `glGetUniformLocation (...)` returns a ***signed*** integer value, there are more bad things going on in this code than confusing variable names. Every part of the GL API that refers to uniform locations uses *signed* integers. I would expect a tutorial author to pay attention to compiler warnings before publishing code :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Some OpenGL implementations (like AMD and nVidia drivers) tend to return ascending resource ID's, starting from 1. If this is the first texture the code allocates and the sampler is the first uniform in the shader program, then IDs will match, and the code accidentally works. However, it will likely break on other platforms (like Intel drivers), or when more resources are used.

Comment: So the moral lesson is not to mix up texture,shader,uniform IDs right?

Comment: Exactly, they should never be mixed.

Comment: Not necessarily, uniform locations can start at **0** (the only unusable location is **-1** (**0xFFFFFFFF**)). Texture names, on the other hand cannot start at **0**. The texture name **0** is reserved by GL (it is called the *"default"* texture), the lowest value `glGenTextures (...)` could ever return is **1**. There are too many assumptions here already, but if you assume the first uniform in a program is assigned location **0**, this situation *(as described)* would never arise.

Comment: That might very well be true. However, the vertex shader also has a mat4 uniform in the code above. The sampler may then be uniform #1, which causes the collision.

Comment: What vertex shader? I was referring to your statement: *"If this is the first texture the code allocates and the sampler is the first uniform in the shader program, then IDs will match"*. If you assume that uniform locations begin at **0**, then IDs will not match.

Comment: The code linked above has a vertex shader and a fragment shader. The vertex shader has a transformation matrix uniform, and the fragment shader has a sampler uniform. The code requests these two uniform ID's using `GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");` and `GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");`. I assume here, that MatrixID will be 0 and TextureID will be 1.

Comment: Okay, but that's not what your answer says. The answer talks about a "shader program", which is actually a confusion between two different concepts: "shader objects" and "program objects". Since shader objects do not have uniforms, I assume you mean program object. If it were the first uniform in the linked program object, then it would have location **0**.